# node chaining promise doesn't return resolved value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to chain a promise which will take an input, append to the input, pass back the result before finally resolving the Promise.  Code executes and I had added some console.log so I know that the value of _add24h is getting appended but it seems the .then does not pass to the main Promise as it finally resolves to the initial value.

My Promise.all elsewhere in the code is getting values passed but does not contain the data from the .then

```
promise2 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    binance.prevDay(coin + `BTC`, (error, prevDay, symbol) => {
        for (var obj in prevDay) {
            if (obj.includes("priceChange")) {
                _add24h["24h Change"] = `\u0E3F` + prevDay[obj];
            }
        }
        resolve(_add24h);
    })
    }).then(function(_add24h) {
        return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
            binance.prevDay(coin + `USDT`, (error, prevDay, symbol) => {
                for (var obj in prevDay) {
                    if (obj.includes("priceChange")) {
                         _add24h["24h Change"] = _add24h["24h Change"] + "\n$" + parseFloat(prevDay[obj]).toFixed(2);
                    }
                }
            })
        })
        resolve(_add24h);
    })

Promise.all([promise1,promise2]).then(function(_addFields) {
    Object.keys(_addFields).forEach(function(prop) {
        Object.keys(_addFields[prop]).forEach(function(key) {
            embed.addField(key,_addFields[prop][key],true)
        });
    });
    message.channel.send({embed});
});
```

Comment: What is promise1 here?

Comment: Also _add24h is not defined in the first promise, I assume it is used somewhere outside? Looks like a source of bugs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)

Answer (score 0):

If you are resolving secon promise outside of your callback so it is actually getting resolved even before `binance.prevDay(coin + 'USDT',...)` run.

So you need to change your call as follow and enclose resolve in callback

```
promise2 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    binance.prevDay(coin + `BTC`, (error, prevDay, symbol) => {
        for (var obj in prevDay) {
            if (obj.includes("priceChange")) {
                _add24h["24h Change"] = `\u0E3F` + prevDay[obj];
            }
        }
        resolve(_add24h);
    })
})
.then(function(_add24h) {
    return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
        binance.prevDay(coin + `USDT`, (error, prevDay, symbol) => {
            for (var obj in prevDay) {
                if (obj.includes("priceChange")) {
                     _add24h["24h Change"] = _add24h["24h Change"] + "\n$" + parseFloat(prevDay[obj]).toFixed(2);
                }
            }
            resolve(_add24h);
        })
    })
 })
```

Comment: I tried the changes you suggested but I'm still not getting a callback.  Added some console.log before and after the _add24h object concat during second promose and also a console.log just before the resolve in the first promise which produces this output

This is the output.  I know the object is being updated with my concat value, but return is still not passing back the concat value.
Return฿0.00047700
Before฿0.00047700
After฿0.00047700
$8.80

Comment: @JK sorry, I did one mistake so updating answer.